# Visual Studio C++ Application wont run on 32bit computer

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, 32-bit

I have a program that I made in Visual Studio 2010. I built the program in release mode and Win32 solution platform. I then made an executable by following [this guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293575(v=VS.100).aspx) step by step. I then copied the setup.exe that was created onto a new **32-bit** computer. I then get this error message when I try to run the setup on the new computer:

[image]

Why is the setup not working? I built the program in Win32, so it should work on a 32-bit computer? Am i missing something? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What specific OS is the computer running?

Comment: both the system that I wrote the code on and the new system are running Windows 7 Professional

Comment: are you sure that computer has .net framework installed same as your visual studio 2010?

Comment: Yes, both versions have 4.5.2 installed but the computer that I wrote the code on also has "Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Multi-Targeting Pack" Do I need that on the other one?

Comment: Check if you are really building for x86: Go to Project Properties -> Linker -> Advanced and look at the Target Machine value. What does it say?

Comment: You don't need a .Net framework for a Win32 C++ project.

Comment: @Mailerdaimon yes that could be the problem! The target machine is Machine x64. So if I change that to Machine x86 it should work? Or do I need to change other values?

Comment: It should work with changing to x86. Just try it ;-). You can always check the Machine Type of your Exe and its DLLs with the tool: "Dependency Walker" if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mailerdaimon and @MSalters you were correct. Even though I was building the program in win32, the target machine was x64. After changing it to x86 the program ran. Thanks for everyones help!

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 major reasons for this to happen. The Windows executables contain 3 fields that must be matched by the OS: Minimal OS version number, correct CPU type and correct CPU bit-ness. Now you're probably not running into a Windows version issue (I think the error message is different), you're quite unlikely to have the wron CPU type (ARM builds are pretty hard to make by accident) so that leaves as the most likely scenario that you actually made a 64 bits build.

"Win32" is a rather deceiving term here, it doesn't always exclude 64 bits builds. E.g. the *macro* `WIN32` is defined for 64 bits builds as well.